# hls ext-x-discontinuity-sequence for endless stream

Tags: http-live-streaming, exoplayer, hls.js

In an endless HLS stream, I'm not sure how to implement the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE tag.
The RFC states :

> If the server removes an EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag from the Media
> Playlist, it MUST increment the value of the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-
> SEQUENCE tag so that the Discontinuity Sequence Numbers of the
> segments still in the Media Playlist remain unchanged.  The value of
> the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE tag MUST NOT decrease or wrap.
> Clients can malfunction if each Media Segment does not have a
> consistent Discontinuity Sequence Number.

The media playlist I create always have the same number of segments, and the older one gets deleted when a newer one is added. Sometimes, there might be a discontinuity between two segments, so I add an EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY to the segment. However, after some time, when there are no more discontinuities in the playlist, I remove this tag and should increment the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE.

Since the stream is endless, it will have to wrap at some point. How do people usually implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE` is defined as a `decimal-integer` which is defined as a number in the range 0 - 2^64 - 1 (see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis-09#section-4.2)

Even if you were incrementing `EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE` many many times a second (which the question implies you are not) it seems highly unlikely you would need to handle wrapping of this value.

Given the possible range and relatively slow incrementing in the general case, I seriously doubt anyone worries about wrapping this value, but I'd be interested to be proved wrong.